# Multiple socket.io instances at different paths

Tags: node.js, rest, http, socket.io

I'm making a REST API that works with routes and actions like `/api/route/action`. But I want to add WebSocket functionalities. So I want WebSockets to also be addressable by url.

I have this code:

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');

//server is a http.createServer()
module.exports = server => {
    const io = socketio(server, { route: '/socketapi/test' );
    io.on('connection', s => { 
        s.on('a', () => s.emit('b'));
        s.emit('message', 'You connected to /test.');
    });

    const io2 = socketio(server, { route: '/socketapi/something_else' });
    io2.on('connection', s => { 
        s.on('z', () => s.emit('y'));
        s.emit('message', 'Hi');
    });
};
```

The reason why I want to split them is so I don't have to keep track of event names I've already used, and so I can separate the logic in the connection event.

But it seems this is not possible. If I have two socket.io instances running I can't connect to either.

Is this possible or will I have to use some tricks and perhaps an event that the client can send to let me know what it wants to subscribe to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a built in feature of `socket.io` called namespaces to achieve this behaviour.

Here is a basic example:

**Server side:**

```
const nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected');
});
nsp.emit('hi', 'everyone!');
```

**Client side:**

```
const socket = io('/my-namespace');
```

Now the client can emit and receive messages which are specific to a namespace. With the use of namespaces your problem of name conflicts of the events, will be solved.